# How do I communicate between/connect two tomcat servers

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I am working on a project where I have two servers (tomcat), Server A gives initial snapshot of information from DB(MySQL) to the frontend. Server B to serve updates to server A, both servers need to communicate. How do I connect them? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: more information as to what connection between them is necessary. Why not have a third mysql server that both use?

Comment: basically i need the 2 servers to communicate because Server A needs to be the server that updated the DB. Server B can only push the changes as far as Server A.

Comment: I am actually not sure what type of connection is necessary, that was not specified to me. From online research I found Client Server socket connections, i'm not sure if that can be used for Server Server connections

Comment: @user12888775 What does Server B start the comunication to Server A? Is it interaction trom a 3rd party? Is it timer programmed events?

Comment: Postman will update information in ServerB, serverB needs to communicate only the changes (using timer programmed events) to serverA, which will update the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways two Tomcat instances running on the same host could be set up to communicate with each other.  It's quite common to implement a REST service in the "server" Tomcat instance and have the "client" Tomcat instance send the REST request to the other instance.  It's common to use either the Jersey or CXF framework to implement a JAX-RS REST service, or you could use the Spring framework to implement a more general web request handler.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat typically accepts HTTP/S requests. So you could program your own servlets in Tomcat A (and publish them as URIs) to accept data which shall be updated to the DB. Then, Server B must act as a client to server A, initiating communication whenever it wants, and sending the data to Server A as HTTP requests.

Taking security into account, I'd also suggest that Server A should forbid any requests to the updating URIs which do not come from Server B. For instance, securizing the updating URIs through standard JEE security.